# Choppy slide titles animation in Premiere

Tags: video, premiere, animation

Look at what I mean: [Youtube link](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9HUpYYJoA8Y&feature=youtu.be)

Titles slide to the center all choppy, laggy, like they are skipping frames... I tried with better quality 1920 etc... but all that does is enlarge my picture which isn't really helpful considering I have a small raster picture to start with and the animation is still sluggish. What gives?

These are my Adobe Premiere Pro CS6 settings for exporting video:

```
format:h.264
w: 320, h: 240
frame rate: 30
aspect: D1/DV PAL (1.0940)
TV standard: NTSC
Profile: high
level: 1,3
render at maximum depth: "checked"

bitrate encoding: VBR, 1 pass
target and maximum bitrate: 0,18

use maximum render quality: "checked"
```

PS.: How can I improve quality of the video, setting it to 1920*1080 just enlarges my video, which pixelates my raster picture in the video.

Comment: What is the actual frame rate on your sequence in Premiere?  Faster frame rate in export won't help if the sequence frame rate is slow.

Comment: hmmm, how do I check the sequence frame rate?

Comment: I don't have Premiere in front of me at the moment, but I believe it is the properties of the sequence.  Try right clicking in the list of media for the project or using the Sequence menu while you have the sequence open.